# NatTable 1.6 - TreeLayer - expand/collapse triangles don't follow their rows after collapsing a row above

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

When I collapse a row in a TreeLayer in NatTable, its children disappear, and other rows move up.

In NatTable 1.5.0, the expand/collapse icons move up with their rows.

In NatTable 1.6.0, the expand/collapse icons stay at their original row index, where their rows used to be.

Do I need to do something extra in 1.6? For example, to cause the tree layer to update from its ITreeRowModel?

**EDIT**

Here's an illustration of the issue. It occurs when NatTable is upgraded to 1.6, with no other code changes.

[image: illustration of issue]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Any screenshots or examples to show this?

Comment: I tested in the NatTable examples and do not see any issue. Are you using default mechanisms or have you overriden/customized stuff?

Comment: @DirkFauth - I've added an illustration. I also don't see this happening in the examples. I'm not using glazed lists at all. Data and tree models are defined atop a custom data layer. Yes, I've taken advantage of NatTable's configurability. I understand that answering this may be difficult without a small, self-contained example, that I have not yet built.

Comment: Maybe some fix is causing this with your customization. Seems like an issue with position index transformation, but without further details on your customization I am not able to help.

Comment: Might be a regression although I am not sure why. You could try to debug in TreeLayer#getConfigLabelsByPosition() to see if there internally a processing fails somehow.

Comment: @DirkFauth - Thanks for the idea. Maybe we were relying on some behavior that was not guaranteed and changed. Your observation that the examples work suggests there's something we can do in our own code. But currently I'm nearing the end of a release. I downgraded back to 1.5 for the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a regression that was not noticed. Mainly because most of the people seem to use `TreeLayer` with GlazedLists. And the NatTable project did not even have an example for usage without GlazedLists.

I have created a ticket and fixed the issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=552727

You could workaround the issue in the meanwhile by overriding `TreeLayer#getConfigLabelsByPosition(int, int)` the following way:

```
public LabelStack getConfigLabelsByPosition(int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
    LabelStack configLabels = super.getConfigLabelsByPosition(columnPosition, rowPosition);

    if (isTreeColumn(columnPosition)) {
        configLabels.addLabelOnTop(TREE_COLUMN_CELL);

        ILayerCell cell = getCellByPosition(columnPosition, rowPosition);
        if (cell != null) {
            int rowIndex = getRowIndexByPosition(cell.getOriginRowPosition());
            configLabels.addLabelOnTop(
                    DefaultTreeLayerConfiguration.TREE_DEPTH_CONFIG_TYPE + this.treeRowModel.depth(rowIndex));
            if (!this.treeRowModel.hasChildren(rowIndex)) {
                configLabels.addLabelOnTop(DefaultTreeLayerConfiguration.TREE_LEAF_CONFIG_TYPE);
            } else {
                if (this.treeRowModel.isCollapsed(rowIndex)) {
                    configLabels.addLabelOnTop(DefaultTreeLayerConfiguration.TREE_COLLAPSED_CONFIG_TYPE);
                } else {
                    configLabels.addLabelOnTop(DefaultTreeLayerConfiguration.TREE_EXPANDED_CONFIG_TYPE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return configLabels;
}
```

Main issue is the missing transformation of the origin row position to index in the 1.6 implementation.

Comment: Thank you for solving the issue despite the limited information in my question. I'm impressed.